# SELECT from multiple tables using composite PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
Users: 
+--------+------+
| UserID | Name |
+--------+------+
|      1 |  Bob |
|      2 | Mike |
|      3 |  Tim |
|      4 |  Joe |
+--------+------+

Friends: 
+---------+---------+
| UserID1 | UserID2 |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       2 |
|       1 |       3 |
|       3 |       4 |
|       4 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Now let's say Bob logs on to my service. I need to run a query that will load all of his friends' UserIDs as well as their Names.

```
Bob's friends: 
+--------+------+
| UserID | Name |
+--------+------+
|      2 | Mike |
|      3 |  Tim |
+--------+------+
```

Note that the "Friends" table has a composite primary key, using both UserID1 and UserID2. Each "friendship" is only listed in the table once.

What would be the best way to tackle this? In other words, what query should I use to find the friends of a user consisting of both their UserID and Name? Obviously some kind of JOIN clause will be needed to select data from multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friendship is listed only once in the table. If the example data represents `Mike` as having three friends, then we need to query the `friends` table both ways. I'd use two SELECTs and combine the results with a `UNION ALL` set operator. Like this:

```
SELECT uf.userid
     , uf.name
  FROM users uf
  JOIN friends ff
    ON ff.userid1 = uf.userid
  JOIN users sf
    ON sf.userid = ff.userid2
 WHERE sf.name = 'Mike'
 UNION ALL
SELECT ut.userid
     , ut.name
  FROM users ut
  JOIN friends ft
    ON ft.userid2 = ut.userid
  JOIN users st
    ON st.userid = ft.userid1
 WHERE st.name = 'Mike'
```

There are other query approaches that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: That is a very elaborated answer to what seems a simple question at a quick glance. May I with all the due respect suggest to alter `UNION ALL` to `UNION`? That's because no-one will keep us from inserting `(2, 4)` into table `friends`. `UNION` will eliminate a doubled result. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1fa/4). Do you know a way (other then a trigger) to prevent the insert of a reversed key here?

Comment: Using `UNION` in place of `UNION ALL` will cause MySQL to perform a "sort unique" operation to eliminate duplicate rows. And that can be expensive on large sets. Where that operation is not required, we usually get better performance with a `UNION ALL`. The question specified that a friendship was stored only once in the table. You are absolutely correct that if both (2,4) and (4,2) are stored in the table, this query would return "duplicate" results. And no I don't know of any way the database can enforce a constraint against redundant rows without a trigger.

Answer (score 3):

First, you want to join to find out who Bob's friends are. Then you need to join back, to see the names of his friends.

```
SELECT u2.* FROM users u1 
JOIN friends ON friends.userid1 = u1.userid
JOIN users u2 ON u2.userid = friends.userid2
WHERE u1.name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: instead select the specific columns as this will result in unnecessary columns.

Comment: In general yes but in this case it will not